# How can I prevent getting a dialog popup window to login with basic authentication?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, basic-authentication

Currently we are trying to access the reed.co.uk api and get the json results of jobs from an account. I have managed to access the API in chrome and get the results but in Safari (Version 10.0.1 (12602.2.14.0.7)) and Firefox(v 50.1.0) I get the dialog pop up that asks me to log in.

I have tried multiple versions of Ajax to get this working but nothing seems to fix the issue at all. Here is what I have got:

```
var clientId = "c*****-***-****-****-*********0";
var clientSecret = "";

var authorizationBasic = $.base64.btoa(clientId + ':' + clientSecret);

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/search?employerId=488552',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + authorizationBasic
    },
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + authorizationBasic);
    },
    statusCode: {
        401: function () {
            result = false;
        },
        200: function (response) {
            result = response;
        }
    },
    async: false,
    success: function (result) {
        var token = result;
        console.log(token);
    },
    //complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    //},
    error: function (req, status, error) {
    alert(error);
    }
});
```

Request headers Chrome:

[image]

Request headers firefox

[image]

This is the information reed.co.uk returns to you when accessing the results from their API:

> You will need to include your api key for all requests in a basic
>   authentication http header as the username, leaving the password
>   empty.

Can anyone see why this would happen?

Comment: Open the developers tool bar and check the actual request you make. See if there are any differences between the browsers

Comment: There are no differences that I can see

Comment: Have you tried clearing firefox's cache? FF could have cached the incorrect response

Comment: Request headers in chrome are missing

Comment: sorry I cropped them off

Comment: Well... They are needed :)

Comment: try dataType: "json", instead of dataType: "jsonp"

Comment: If I do this in chrome and clear the cache it asks again also to login. This must be how reed.co.uk allow GET requests for their jobs?

Comment: Instead of sending the Authorization header yourself, have you tried to just supply the jQuery.ajax parameters `username` and `password` with the appropriate values (password an empty string in this case), and see if that works if you just let jQuery handle it …?

Comment: I believe the withCredentials will only work when the Access-Control-Allow-Origin specifies an origin (it can't be *) - see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19644015/cors-request-failure-with-jquery-using-withcredentials-and-client-certificates

Comment: Hi I cannot modify how reed.co.uk output their headers on 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' all I can do is oass my api keu through the username data with basic authentication as explained above

Comment: I understand, but it seems that withCredentials won't work then.  Have you tried http://user:pass@www.reed.co.uk/... ?

Comment: No because I am thinking that would not be the best approach to it looking at their limited docs